# What is the best/recommended OS to run a stake pool?

Tags: stake-pool, proof-of-stake, spo

What is the best/recommended Linux OS to run a stake pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely ***[Linux](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/operate-a-stake-pool/)***, thanks to its *command-line* and *server* capabilities.

[NixOS 21](https://nixos.org) is a worthy candidate.

Comment: What flavor of Linux?

Comment: For example NixOS. It's a GNU/Linux distribution that uses Nix as both a package manager and a configuration manager.

Comment: What about FreeBSD ? Did somebody try it out ? Does it work ?

Comment: Sorry @Jey, I haven't run it on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1):

On ARM hardware such as a Raspberry Pi 4B, I highly recommend this [Alpine Linux](https://armada-alliance.com/guides/run-a-cardano-node-on-alpine-linux-os) setup written about by some members of the Armada Alliance of SPOs. It does a great job running Cardano static binaries while using very little power, CPU, and memory.

My pool (Adaberry Pi [00000]) runs both Alpine and Ubuntu nodes very reliably on these little single-board computers.

Comment: is it still running with the new node version?

Comment: The RPi 4B 8G runs 1.34.1 without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I am a Windows expert since 3.0 (1988), and Linux/Unix almost as long.  I am proficient in Windows 2019 and 10.  Although there is a Windows solution for running a Cardano stake pool, I would not recommend it for many reasons.  As far as Linux distros go, Ubuntu is an excellent one that I have worked with for almost 15 years, and I highly recommend it.  It is backed by a successful commercial enterprise, but it is free to the community.  As a Debian fork, it is relatively easy to use and well-supported.  And, if that isn't enough to convince you, the shell scripts and installation documentation & courses are all using it as an example.

One thing you should know, is that Ubuntu labels their OS versions by year and 6-month release cycle.  So for example, 18.04 was released in 2018 in April, while 18.10 was released in October.  The April releases are more proven/solid, the October releases more experimental.  Every other year is a Long-Term-Support release, or LTS, so 20.04 LTS has a longer-term support commitment from Canonical Software.

Also, for the Stake Pool I operate (PLL), I did some research and it is recommended to apply automatic OS updates, so we enabled that.

If you need more help, give us a shout on Telegram at https://t.me/tprevolution

Answer (score 0):

For `cardano-node` 1.30.1, it is:

> - Linux 64-bit (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS; Mint 19.3, 20; Debian 10.3)
> - Windows 64-bit (8.1, 10)
> - MacOS 10.13, 10.14, 10.15